# How to close a Windows 8 application programmatically?

Tags: windows, html, windows-8

I'm building an application for Windows 8 and need to be able to close it programmatically using an action. For example, a button on my application.

I'm building my application using HTML5

Comment: Why do you need to close your application programmatically?

Comment: I'm creating a game , and after it's done , i'm asking the user if he want to play another one or not !!

Comment: You shouldn't have to stop your application to ask the user to play another game - just navigate back to your start page and discard the internal state for your game.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following event handler worked for me...I actually put an Exit icon in a global app bar...users love it!

```
        private void closeButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            App.Current.Exit();
        }
```

Good Luck!

This solution above works for C#...it's especially helpful when using Windows 8 Store Apps on machines that are not touch screen capable (our users were having difficulty emulating the top down swipe to close an app...other users are running a Windows 8 on a Mac VM which makes the Alt + F4 tough)

Comment: @PatrickKlug - I understand the question was about Windows 8 Store Apps...and, yes it is possible to close from within the app.  So why the down vote? Just curious.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot.  The Windows Runtime API (and the modern subset of the windows SDK) don't provide mechanisms to terminate applications.

The model for Windows Runtime based applications is to allow the system or the user to manage the process lifetime.

Answer (score 3):

In JS you can do this:

```
window.close();
```

Comment: This is awesome; look me several hours to find something in javascript that worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can't close an app programmatically, it's the system's choice.